# Helm v3 cannot find my charts in private repo

Tags: kubernetes, charts, cloud, kubernetes-helm

I have a private helm repo using apache, after migrating to helm3 I cannot install/search charts anymore.

Using helm v3

```
helm repo list
NAME    URL
mas     http://localhost:8080/charts/

helm search repo mas/devops-openshift
No results found
```

Using helm 2.*

```
helm search -r mas/devops-openshift
NAME                    CHART VERSION          APP VERSION    DESCRIPTION       
mas/devops-openshift    7.0.0                                 Devops (OpenShift)
```

Same happens when using "helm install" command, it cannot find the charts.

I guess it could be something related to the helm repo index file. Maybe helmv3 is expecting a different structure? But same happen when generating index file from helmv3.

Comment: One possible reason is that your local helm version is not compatible with the tiller version. What are your helm and tiller versions?

Comment: In the `helm2` command you use regex (`-r`) anb in the Helm 3 command you don't have it. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: After migrating to v3 remove private repo, add it after migration and run helm repo update.
If you have it packed locally try to run `helm repo index `to create index.yaml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers but I've found the issue.
My repository were using development version of the charts so I had something like this 1.0.0-pre.dev (Semantic Versioning 2.0.0).
By default helm 3 does not look at non production charts.
You have to set the flag -devel. something like:
`helm search repo mas/devops-openshift --devel`

Answer (score 0):

While [migrating from helm 2 to helm 3](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/) remove private repo and add it after migration, then run `helm repo update` to refresh repository file.

If the chart is available locally, run `helm repo index <DIR> --url <your_repo_url>` to create new `index.yaml` for this repository.
Running `helm env` will show you the directory where the `repository.yaml`is located so check if the file is generated correctly.